# replace matching text in hyperlink href

Tags: javascript, jquery

What im trying to do is find all hyperlinks that have a href like this `herf="/grade4/chapter1.html"`
and replace the chapter word with `href="grade4/chapter_af1.html"`

i have tried a few jquery tricks but have had no luck

```
$('a').each( function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var href = $this.attr('href').replace(/\chapter/,'chapter_af');
    $this.attr('href', href );
});
```

Comment: Why not change them in the source?

Comment: try removing the \ `replace(/chapter/,'chapter_af');`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a regular expression, just do a normal string replace:

http://jsfiddle.net/9MXSZ/

```
$('a').each( function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var href = $this.attr('href').replace('chapter','chapter_af');
    $this.attr('href', href );
});
```

If you really want to use a regex, the `\` in your version is throwing it off:

```
.replace(/chapter/,'chapter_af')
```

Answer (score 0):

No need of `Regex` here.

Try simply like this

```
var href = $this.attr('href').replace('chapter','chapter_af');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your replace statement to:

```
...
var href = $(this).attr('href').replace('chapter', 'chapter_af')
...
```

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/vNCpV/